# How to access a static method from a instance method in mongoose?

Tags: static, mongoose, instance

How to access a static method from a instance method in mongoose?

I have a job model named Job. From a instance method job.start I want to call the static method Job.someStatic(). How do I get the reference to the Job, from the "this" in the instance method?

thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The only way I've found to do that generically (without just calling `Job.someStatic()`) is:

```js
this.model(this.constructor.modelName).someStatic();
```

**Update** thanks to @numbers1311407:

I don't know if it's always been the case, but as of at least Mongoose 3.6.11, you can shorten this to:

```js
this.constructor.someStatic();
```

**Mongoose 4.x Update**

This still works in 4.4.12.

Comment: oh, that's ugly to... But here is what I'm doing: when I'm creating the models I set a method on the model itself. (Job.abc = function(){}) I think this is static. It's there any other way to pass a function to a instance?

Comment: Why aren't you adding that function to the schema's `statics` instead?

Comment: I don't have access to that static. But your method works too.. I would like something more shorter sintax, but I can live with it. If you come to mind with something more compact, I'm glad to hear

Comment: Doesn't `this.constructor === this.model(this.constructor.modelName)`?

Comment: Calling Job.someStatic() from dynamic method did not even work for me... this.constructor had the right pointer though!

Comment: I have the same problem but the solution mentioned in this answer does not work for Mongoose 4.4.x. Anyone got a clue how to do this in a later Mongoose version?

Comment: @Martijn I just tested this with Mongoose 4.4.12 and it worked fine. Best to post a new question about it if you can't get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to access statics is:

```
this.schema.statics.someStatic()
```